# I want to push objects into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

i have written this code, but this does not work, please help me to find out the problem.

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
var obj = {
    x : i, y : 2
};
arr.push(obj);
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
Document.write(arr[i].x +" "+arr[i].y+"<br>" );
}
```

Comment: `Document` should be `document`.

Comment: And after this example you should learn about DOM manipulating methods like createElement, appendChild, insertBefore or maybe innerHTML ... and forget about document.write

Comment: The cardinal rule of programming errors: when in doubt, your problem is some tiny syntax error.

Comment: check your console for errors. When something isn't working correctly check for errors first. Generally that will give you your best clue as to what is wrong. In this case, you should get something similar to "TypeError: Object function Document() { [native code] } has no method 'write'". Which would give you a clue that something isn't correct there (answer is what destroy said)...

Comment: There's no real reason to use two loops either.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
var obj = {x : i, y : 2};
arr.push(obj);
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
alert(arr[i].x +" "+arr[i].y+"<br>" );
}
```

[Check the output here](http://jsfiddle.net/asvignesh/LWnAV/)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive, so you should replace

```
Document.write(arr[i].x +" "+arr[i].y+"<br>" );
```

with

```
document.write(arr[i].x +" "+arr[i].y+"<br>" );
```

But this is only half the answer :

- this error should not have made it to SO : [using the console you should have found it yourself](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)
- `document.write` is a very crude solution to build your page, [it only works during the initial load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write). This means you must learn about the functions which let you [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to the page.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` syntax was wrong try this:

```
document.write(arr[i].x +" "+arr[i].y +"< br/>");
```